# MPMoviePlayerController streaming issue

Tags: ios, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

There is some strange issue I'm currently struggling with.
I have IIS web server one of the purposes of which is data storage. 
It stores video files in database and provides the content of file requested via http (like http://example.com/GetFileContent/id12345)
When I try to feed this url to MPMoviePlayerController it's unable to playback video just showing black screen with busy indicator.
I was capturing http traffic and could see the sequence of HTTP 206 Partial requests with Range header but for some reason some of these requests fail (reset by peer).

Another strange thing is that when I put the same file in web project directory and feed direct url to MPMoviePlayerController (like http://example.com/12345.mp4) everything works fine - video is playing.

I was simulating partial download using first method and 100% sure it sends back proper content (taking Range header values in account).
So what can be wrong? I believe it's a king of IIS misconfiguration.

Comment: Are you attempting to use HTTP Live Stream, or progressive download streaming?

Comment: I feel like this is good question) Unfortunately I do not know the answer yet. Is it a configuration of player or server?

Comment: It's both, more server. In order to stream video over HTTP live stream, you need to have the video file specially prepared, splint into ~10 second chunks and preferably in varying qualities for adaptive bit rate, along with a special playlist file (.m3u8). Have a look here https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Comment: You could also look into progressive download server configs, but Apple does place limitations on file sizes that can be streamed to iOS apps over 3G